Cant run my react native setup project by following the steps give by the react native website (in vs code)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: C:\Users\xxx.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-8.8-all\6gdy1pgp427xkqcjbxw3ylt6h\gradle-8.8-all.zip
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(SourceFile:71)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
I couldn't find ans in youtube tutorials

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
